# Read & set location data each frame

Tags: python, animation, modifiers

I would like to be able to read the XYZ location data of say emptyA and then be able to set that location to emptyB with an offsey of X numbers of frames. I'm looking to be able to set up a "trailing" effect but without baking my animation(s).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Python for that, you can import one object's NLA strip into another object's animation and offset it. Below I'm also duplicating the NLA strip to keep the loop:

[image]

Comment: Wow….I really have to learn more about NLA. Until Noemi solved this with python…‍♂️